# Simple print example

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, media

I need to provide a `print` link on my simple html page.

When the user clicks on that, I want a pop-up which displays a `print preview` and the system printer should come up. I guess something with `window.print();` option, but this directly gives the window print option without the preview.
I want the page preview first and then call window.print(); An example html would help...

More over the example you provide can also have media type print in it. So that the normal html color looks red. But when the print link is selected we need to show print preview in blue color. I know this could be overridden methods using `@media print` in css file.

Any example please...Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? You answered both questions in your question itself.

Comment: He's asking for an example ... "Any examples please" should've hinted at that :)

Comment: @Blender I know by adding window.print would load the print option
`<form>
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
</form>`
But it would not display the print preview first. How can I do it?

Comment: That'll be hard to do, as most browsers apply their own custom styles to every page being printed (even if it has no `@media print`) stylesheet. You have to account for this somehow.

Comment: I know Firefox automatically removes all backgrounds when printing. There was something else it removed too but I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print preview feature is client specific. The latest chrome displays a print preview but most other browsers just display the print dialog upon calling the print() method.

Concerning print styling you should read up on print stylesheets. The A-list-apart article by Eric Meyer from a few years back is a good start with some decent examples.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose report.html is the page you want to print. Develop the page in such a way that it accepts a media argument as a GET paramater. i.e. something like `yoursite.com/report.html?media=X` - where X can be `'screen'`, `'print'` etc. If X is empty, it can use the default value of 'screen'

Write 2 css files namely screen.css and print.css - Depending on this value of the media argument (X) import either screen.css or print.css into your page.

In screen.css, write your style defs inside a '@media screen' block like:

```
@media screen {
  body {
  ... screen style here ...
  }
}
```

In print.css, write your style defs inside a '@media screen, print' block like:

```
@media screen, print {
  body {
  ... print style here ...
  }
}
```

In your report.html, suppose you have a print button, in its `onclick`, call `window.open('report.html?media=print', ...)`. Also do the same from a keydown handler attached to your document object on receiving a Ctrl+P.

Also, in your page's `onload`, check if the media argument is 'print' and if it is then call `window.print()` after a short delay (say 500ms), i.e. something like:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('media=print')!=-1) {
  setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 500);
}
```